# Gsheets trying to create a general search box for my master sheet

Tags: google-sheets

so I've stumbled upon a problem and forgive me for my inexperience I'm still new and trying to learn so bear with me on this one please.
So I'm using google sheets and I have a master sheet with all the data.
I want on another sheet to be able to have 2 or 3 search boxes that can sort the information appropriately.

I'm currently using =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(" link " , "'Master Data'!A:Y"),("SELECT * WHERE Col4 CONTAINS '"&C3&"' ")) this formula but I want it to be for multiple columns not just one.

I tried putting in Col1,Col2 but that didn't work out and I've tried some other formulas but none of them do what I want them to do. I also tried putting in * but that didn't work either.

Basically imagine you have,

Col1  Col2   Col3    Col4 ...
ID    Name  Company  Project

Right now with my formula if I type a random project name it's going to pull out all the projects and people, companies etc.. associated with that project.

What I want is if I type in C3 the name of the project I want to additionally short that data with let's say a certain company name.
That's basically the goal.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("id", "Master Data!A:Y"), 
 "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, "9=9", 
 IF(C3="",, "Col1 = "&C3), 
 IF(C4="",, "Col2 = '"&C4&"'"), 
 IF(C5="",, "Col3 = '"&C5&"'"), 
 IF(C6="",, "Col4 = '"&C6&"'")), 1)
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("1fKYRO7A686Q2X6MxqLaiMBs6pZi_FdQ4PWaM7v1CFWg", "Data!A6:Y")),
 "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, "9=9", 
 IF(C3="",, "Col3 contains '"&TO_TEXT(C3)&"'"), 
 IF(D3="",, "lower(Col4) contains '"&LOWER(D3)&"'"), 
 IF(E3="",, "lower(Col5) contains '"&LOWER(E3)&"'")), 1))
```

[image]

Comment: =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("id", "Master Data!A:Y"), 
 "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, "24=24", 
 IF(C3="",, "Col1 = '"&C3&"'"), 
 IF(C4="",, "Col2 = '"&C4&"'"), 
 IF(C5="",, "Col3 = '"&C5&"'"), 
 IF(C6="",, "Col4 = '"&C6&"'")), 1)
Thank you!
I did a few changes only column 4 worked for me, now Column 1 and Column 4 work but only separately, Col2 and Col3 don't work for some reason, same if you try to use Column 1 and Column 4 together, they return blank results if I try to combine them.

https://prnt.sc/1y7pkuo - pic

Comment: @KristiqnNenov hard to say from your picture/question but if the column contains number then do not use single quotes. I see numbers in your 3rd column so the formula should be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC4tP.png can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: for column 2 you can change `=` to `contains` for partial matches. also note that this all is case sensitive so you may consider wrapping `Col2` into `lower(Col2)` and `&C4&` into `&LOWER(C4)&`

Comment: Hi guys thank you so much but this code just continues to add more and more queries and doesn't stop so I removed it. If you want to help me https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fKYRO7A686Q2X6MxqLaiMBs6pZi_FdQ4PWaM7v1CFWg/edit?usp=sharing this is my link, feel free to do anything its a test sheet but overall the same, it just has way way less data but fundamentally it's the same.

I just wanted to have a single cell where I can type in anything say an ID and then filter the results additionally after that. That's my end goal.

Comment: @KristiqnNenov sheet is private

Comment: Ooh..
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fKYRO7A686Q2X6MxqLaiMBs6pZi_FdQ4PWaM7v1CFWg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @KristiqnNenov answer updated